# android wifi direct. setting PBC message and peer list

Tags: android, wifi-direct, wifimanager, wifip2p, wifi

I searched in many topics and forums. But i still don't find the way to do this.

**How can we set the wifi direct request connection message.**

And so.
How can we set the peer info list to see not just is android ID, but things like a pseudo, a player level or rank, etc...

Any help is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer is: You don't.

Basically the peer list shows just peer information. If you need more then you need to do Service discovery after the peer discovery. Though if you do just quick discovery, then its rather safe to do only Service discovery. For reference [see my blog article](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=81)

With service discovery you could deliver data wither via Bonjour or UPnP. 
With UPnP limitations for data delivery are summarized in [here](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=129).

And with Bonjour you could either deliver some 100 bytes of data via instance name variable in service advertisement, or have data added to Dns-Sd records. The limitations are summarized also in [my blog](http://www.drjukka.com/blog/wordpress/?p=131).

Comment: Many thanks. This is what i thinked but i wanted someone to confirm.